# how to upgrade rails application from ruby 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade

I have my current application in Ruby 1.9.3 and I want to migrate it to ruby 2.0. I have googled it but couldn't find any resource that clearly describes the steps required to upgrade to 2.0. Can anyone give me the stepwise guide for migrating from ruby 1.9 to 2.0? thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want to migrate from ruby 1.9.2 to 2.0 not rails.

Comment: yeah i noticed that @awais :/

Comment: You can do a bundle install in ruby 2 and see if there are any incompatible gems. Find replacements if necessary. Once you bundle install completes, run your full test suite to see what broke. Fix it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the following steps:

- Install new Ruby Version
- Run bundle install (you may need to update some gems and rails)
- Run tests . (If you have coverage of all of you application. If not run the whole application manually and fix the errors. Most of the errors would be syntax and other small issues.)
- Your application is migrated.

Answer (score 6):

This is a detailed instruction:

1. install new ruby version
2. run all tests
3. fix all errors
4. profit

Comment: The answer is not helpful in any way and does not explain what changes between the versions may break existing code.